# Reading and changing value of a XML Node (Android)

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I'm going to try and explain my problem.
What I have is an Android App, with a Map and Markers. Each time you press the a Marker I get the info of an XML file (Local File set in the raw folder), such as name and visited. I'm using DOM, because is the easiest way I know.

What I'am trying to do is that everytime that the user click in the visited checkbox button, the value of the visited Node of that specific marker change.
Here is an example od the xml file:

```
<marker id="00001" name="Marker1">   
      <visited>Yes</visited>
</marker>
```

Now I need a way to get de Path of the raw folder, for the xml file. I try using a method that receive the tag info, the element info(the xml element already searched) and the newValue:

```
public void setNodeValue(String tag, Element element, String newvalue) {
        try {
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("file:///android_asset/file.xml"));
            NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
                    .getChildNodes();
            Node node = (Node) nodeList.item(0);                
            node.setTextContent(newvalue);

            Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            xformer.transform(new DOMSource(getDom()), result);
} catch ....{
....
}
```

the getDom Method...

```
private Document getDom() {
        Document dom = null;
        try {
            InputStream raw = cont.getApplicationContext().getAssets()
                    .open("file.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = null;
            builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            dom = builder.parse(raw);
        } catch ....{
         }.......
        return dom;

    }
```

If anyone can help, please! :)

Comment: `everytime that the user click in the visited checkbox button, the value of de visited Node of that specific marker change` - It is not possible to change the contents of the `raw` folder. You need to save the file to the app data folder or to the sdcard.

Comment: Where should I copy my xml file then? Do I need to create the data folder?

Comment: I suggest using `this.getExternalFilesDirs`. Normally this is the folder `/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.app`. (you should not hard-code this)

Comment: So, I need to copy them into the asset folder for example. Can I change contents in that foler or I need o copy into a new folder in /sdcard ?
I want to preload the XML, that I created in another program.

Comment: You can not change the content of `assets` either. You can ship the file in assets and copy it to sdcard when the program is started for the first time. Use `getExternalFilesDirs`to get the path on sdcard